# What is the meaning of the "disposed" legal staus in the US?

Tags: united-states

I am looking at the criminal record of a person and I see there:

```
Defendant: Disposed
Disposition: Disposed
```

I've googled it but still didn't get it. Does it mean that the accused person was freed of all the charges or has been convicted by the court? In other word the case was closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying a case is "disposed" means that the case has been closed.

[From The Law Dictionary](https://thelawdictionary.org/article/what-does-disposed-mean-in-a-court-case/):

**What Does Disposed Mean In A Court Case?**

> When a case has been disposed, this means it has been closed. Specific reasons for a case being closed can include dismissal, conviction, admission of guilt, among other reasons. Once a case is officially over, it is removed from the court’s docket. Which simply means there are no further dates for that matter scheduled on the court’s calendar. As a legal term, disposed cases can include any type of case ranging from small claim to more felony charges.